# racecondition - dropdown - knockout - javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a drop down:

```
<select data-bind="options: activeFilters, optionsValue:'value', value:funkyThingActiveFilter, optionsText:'text'"
```

After selecting something from this drop down a function is called to refresh the entire model

```
model.funkyThingActiveFilter.subscribe(function (newVal) {
        model.filterResults();


});
```

The filterResults function then gets an update of the viewmodel via AJAX

```
var url = '@Url.Action(MVC.funkyThingsController.IndexJSON())' + "?funkyThingActiveFilter=" + model.funkyThingActiveFilter();

 $.ajax({
           url: url,
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (returnedData) {
               ko.mapping.fromJS(returnedData, {}, model);
              }
         });
```

The trouble lies this starts a race condition as the subscriber sees the model update.
I've tried putting a knockout throttle on the filterResults function but this just delays the race condition.

I've also tried to create semaphores - where the filterResults function sets a inFunction type variable.  However this didn't work as the bindings seem to be refreshed asynchronously.

How can I stop the page going around in circles?!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this I created a copy of the filters at knockout viewmodel creation time.
I then bound the drop down to the copies, and passed the copies as parameters to the AJAX get.

When the model refreshed these copies were not updated as they were not part of the viewmodel data coming back from the AJAX request.  As a result no race condition.